# Cannot lower case button text in android studio

Tags: android, button, android-studio

I have a trivial question that has been bothering me for a while. I tried to google this but no one seems to have the same problem as me or doesn't see it as an issue. When I make a button in activity_my.xml under layout

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_1_name"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I get a button that looks like 
[image: this][Imgur]

even though my strings code is:

```
<resources>

<string name="app_name">HelloWorld</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="button_1_name">BuTtOn 1</string>
```

I know I am definitely missing something small here, but how do I get lower case/upper case working in the button text?

Thanks!

Comment: Check your different values folder for button_1_name string.

Comment: @lpbug         one year later. still faced the same issue and i landed here and got the solution

Answer (score 553, accepted):

You could add `android:textAllCaps="false"` to the button.

The button text might be transformed to uppercase by your app's theme that applies to all buttons. Check themes / styles files for setting the attribute `android:textAllCaps`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! `android:textAllCaps="false"` did work as a workaround but new buttons that are added are still all capitalized. My styles.xml under res/values does not appear to have the aforementioned attribute. Here's what it had `<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>`

Comment: You are inheriting the theme `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`, that contains that setting. You have to add new explicit property for styling buttons, e.g. `<style name="Widget.Button"  parent="Widget.Button"><item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item></style>`

Comment: After adding this, i am having inflation error with arrayindexoutofboundsexception.

Comment: @usman I doubt that the exception is related to the `textAllCaps` property.  Can you provide more details?

Comment: @StelianMatei if we use textAllCaps in EditText, it crashes.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644616/android-edittext-gives-indexoutofbounds-exception-while-using-textallcaps

Comment: attribute textAllCaps is used only in API Level 14 and higher

Comment: This will not going to work when you are using your own custom class extending Button class.

Answer (score 32):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
</style>

<style name="Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Simple and effective.

Answer (score 10):

It can be done easily by using the following code inside your view in **activity_main.xml**:

```
android:textAllCaps="false"
```

In your case it would be as follows:

```
 <Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_1_name"
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:textAllCaps="false" />
```

You can also change it for all the buttons in your app  by adding this to your **styles/themes.xml**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
</style>

<style name="Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

It can  also be set Programatically by using the following in **mainActivity.kt or mainActivity.java**:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
btn.setAllCaps(false);
```

Answer (score 9):

This is fixable in the application code by setting the button's TransformationMethod null, e.g.

```
mButton.setTransformationMethod(null);
```

Answer (score 8):

add `android:textAllCaps="false"` in xml button
It's true with this issue.

Comment: This is just repeating [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24880547/1402846).

Comment: I posted a nifty littly answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958909/why-is-my-button-text-forced-to-all-caps-on-lollipop/43711891#43711891

Answer (score 4):

there are 3 ways to do it.

1.Add the following line on style.xml to change entire application

```
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
```

2.Use

```
android:textAllCaps="false"
```

in your `layout-v21`

```
mButton.setTransformationMethod(null);
```

3. add this line under the element(button or edit text) in xml

> android:textAllCaps="false"

regards

Answer (score 3):

You could set like this

```
button.setAllCaps(false);
```

programmatically

Answer (score 3):

In your .xml file within Button add this line--

```
android:textAllCaps="false"
```

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and the [Stelian Matei's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24880547/4744263) answer? Please, don't repeat the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a property in **`<Button>`** that is **android:textAllCaps="false"** that make characters in which you want in your own Small and caps. By Default its became **True** so write this code and make **textAllCaps=false** then you can write text on button in small and Caps letter as per your requirement. 
Complete code for a Button which allow use to write letters as per our requirement.

```
 <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:text="Login for Chat"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

**in XML  Code**
add this line `android:textAllCaps="false"` 
like bellow code

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_1_name"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       ** android:textAllCaps="false" ** />
```

### or

in Java code (**programmatically**)
add this line to your button `setAllCaps(false)`

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
btn.setAllCaps(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this issue in TextView. I have tried

```
android:textAllCaps="false", 
mbutton.setAllCaps(false);   
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
```

none of that worked for me. Finally I fed up and I have hard coded text, **it is working.**

```
tv.setText("Mytext");
```

**tv is object of TextView. But as per coding standards, it is bad practice.**

Answer (score 1):

in XML:
android:textAllCaps="false"

Programmatically:

mbutton.setAllCaps(false);