# Html text (or spannable) in a button don't work after migrating to Android Studio

Tags: android, html, button, android-studio, spannable

```
MyButton.setText(Html.fromHtml("*  <small><sup>^</sup></small>"));
```

With Eclipse :

[image]

With Android Studio :

[image]

It is the same if i use an other method :

```
SpannableStringBuilder cs = new SpannableStringBuilder("*  ^");    
cs.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 1, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
cs.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan((float) 0.50), 1, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
MyButton.setText(cs);
```

Muy buid.graddle configuration is :

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 18
   buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: shouldn't you use 3, 4 instead of 1, 4 ?

Comment: I'm using html mode. The problem is not in programmation but it is the migration to Android Studio !

Comment: Is it the same device api version,  if so which one?

Comment: It's the same on all devices...

Comment: Not possible imho,  what you see is probably not Html version but SpannableStringBuilder, change 1 to 2 and run again

Comment: emlator 2.3, kitkat, Lollilop etc...

Comment: Just tested on kitkat and it's ok, using android studio of course

Comment: Html and spannableStringBuilder works with Eclipse !

Comment: Html works with AS v1.0.1

Comment: Maybe you see the old apk results, is your apk properly deployed?

Comment: After correcting, don't works with AS...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66825/discussion-between-eric-joye-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not migration. I created a new program with AS:

```
    LinearLayout ly = new LinearLayout(this);

    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText(Html.fromHtml("*  <small><sup>^</sup></small>"));

    ly.addView(b);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("*  <small><sup>^</sup></small>"));

    ly.addView(tv);

    setContentView(ly);
```

Result with Android Studio :

[image]

it is working in the textview, but in the button, superscript for "^" character is not present.
The same code in eclipse is working well both for the textview and the button.

I'm using AS 1.0.1 and my buid.graddle configuration is :

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 21
  buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: @pskink The problem is the same with a simple html tag : 
    b.setText(Html.fromHtml("A <b>A</b>"));

Comment: The **SOLUTION** : added
**b.setAllCaps(false);**

Explanations : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880388/cannot-lower-case-button-text-in-android-studio?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

**Try this...**

```
Button byButton = new Button(this);
byButton.setText(Html.fromHtml(" * <small><sup> ^ </sup></small>"));
```