# Android - EditText gives IndexOutOfBounds Exception while using textAllCaps

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I'm trying to create a very simple registration page using a relative layout. This registration page is linked to a fragment called RegistrationFragment.

I have five EditText fields for this layout: name, phone number, email, password, and confirm password. For some reason, I can enter text into password and confirm password, but whenever I try to enter any text into the other fields, they immediately crash the application with an IndexOutOfBounds Exception.

Here's the full stack trace:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1879)
        at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:747)
        at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:898)
        at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:414)
        at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:293)
        at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:267)
        at android.text.Layout.getLineExtent(Layout.java:998)
        at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:329)
        at android.widget.Editor.drawHardwareAccelerated(Editor.java:1380)
        at android.widget.Editor.onDraw(Editor.java:1303)
        at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:5163)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14465)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13362)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3077)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13300)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:13404)
        at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1570)
        at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2377)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2249)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1879)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e5e5e5">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_registration_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:text="@string/registration_title"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_registration_edit_text_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/fragment_registration_title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fragment_registration_legal_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/full_name_prompt"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_top_rounded"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fragment_registration_cell_phone"
        android:layout_below="@id/fragment_registration_legal_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/cell_phone_prompt"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_white"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fragment_registration_email"
        android:layout_below="@id/fragment_registration_cell_phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/email_prompt"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_white"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fragment_registration_password"
        android:layout_below="@id/fragment_registration_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/confirm_password_prompt"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bottom_rounded"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/fragment_registration_button"
    android:background="@drawable/button_registration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/registration_button"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_registration_edit_text_layout"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If relevant, I'm "looking" at my Fragment code using the below, which is at the end of the onCreate() method of my main activity for testing purposes. I got the same errors when I tried testing Registration as an activity though.

```
RegistrationFragment test = new RegistrationFragment();
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_registration);
```

Comment: Post your onClickListener code for EditText

Comment: Try removing `textAllCaps` from the `<EditText />` controls and then see if the error still occurs...

Comment: @Morteza, I had read from somewhere that that may cause an issue, but I actually do not have any onClickListener code for my EditTexts.

Comment: @miselking That was actually the fix! If you'd be willing to make it an answer, I could definitely upvote it. It's really, really strange that that should cause an exception though.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

I had the same problem with `textAllCaps` for `EditText` in my application.

> I have found that `textAllCaps` is a property for `TextView` only. You can not use this property for `EditText`.

So, I did R&D for it and found a better solution for this issue.

> Rather than using `textAllCaps` we can use `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"`.

E.g.

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:hint="@string/first_name"
        android:padding="10dp" >
    </EditText>
```

If we use **`android:inputType="textCapCharacters"`** it will convert all characters into UPPER CASE, like we want in `textAllCaps`.

> **P.S.** If you use the shift key and type text it may convert the text in lowercase. You can always use `toUpper()` method in string object to convert it back to uppercase.
> It may help...

You can read these details from this blog post: https://androidacademic.blogspot.com/2018/05/indexoutofbounds-exception-while-using.html

Comment: This is the correct way to go about dealing with this problem!

Comment: `android:inputType="textCapCharacters"` does not prevent users tapping `Shift` and entering lowercase characters.

Comment: What if I'm using textAllCaps=false for my TabLayout. What should I do instead?

Comment: @Euridice01 textAllCaps is property for TextView only. You should not use it for EditText.

Comment: @Prag'sシ thanks!  I was beginning to bruise my forehead.

Comment: @OllieStrevel  Glad it helped :)

Comment: How to see in some docs or src code what other inherited attributes aren't supported by EditText?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, the problem is that `textAllCaps` is not working for `EditText` controls. It only works for commands that are not editable (like `TextView`). As per documentation on `setAllCaps()` (which is the code behind version of the `textAllCaps`):

> This setting will be ignored if this field is editable or selectable

So, it will not work.

Now, even I am not sure why your code crashed, it shouldn't have, it should have just be ignored, but maybe, the problem occurs when `textAllCaps` is set from the xml file... I wasn't sure, but I just suggested what I would have changed the first, and hoped it would work...

Anyhow, I am glad I helped...

Comment: Hm. I don't have enough reputation to upvote. But you are the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have enough reputation to make a comment but I had a similar runtime exception (and crash) while using a `TextView` and `textAllCaps` set to `true`.

When I removed that setting, everything worked as expected. So it seems that the advice given above can also apply to `TextView` in certain cases.

The same happens when you set `android:digits` and set to `true` `textAllCaps` while using `EditText`. The solution is the same, remove the `textAllCaps`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `textAllCaps` for `TextView` (not `EditText`) but it **crash**
With the same code like yesterday but today it **crash** (yesterday don't crash) (if I remove `textAllCaps` code will run normally)

Some case **WON'T FIX** my problem

- Run it on different device and API
- Clean project
- Restart Android Studio
- Invalid and restart Android Studio
- Restart computer
- Remove **all** another `View`, just only keep 1 `TextView` with `textAllCaps` attribute in layout

Then, I try to run my code on a few different computers and **it WORKING** (my AndroidStudio is as same as another computer)

- Then I try to reset all AndroidStudio settings on my computer -> run the project again -> **it still crashes**

Finally, I remove all things relevant to Android in my computer -> download Android Studio -> install -> run project -> **fortunately it working**

My current AS version is 3.1.14. I am not sure it works in your case or not but hope it helps!