# IndexOutofBound, No Line number shown for error

Tags: java, android, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am newbie in android, I don't know why i am getting following error. I have tried every possible solution but doesn't work for me. It doesn't show any line number where actual error is occurring.

I have tried with different methods and solution, With another way when i try with adapter and other it's working fine but i wanted it to do with this way..

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
   at android.graphics.Paint.getRunAdvance(Paint.java:2360)
   at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:750)
   at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:900)
   at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:419)
   at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:298)
   at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:272)
   at android.text.Layout.getLineExtent(Layout.java:1131)
   at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:428)
   at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:298)
   at android.widget.Editor.onDraw(Editor.java:1575)
   at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:5861)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16381)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16293)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3610)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3400)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16291)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3610)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3400)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16384)
   at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1873)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16293)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3610)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3400)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16384)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16293)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3610)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3400)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16291)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3610)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3400)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16291)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3610)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3400)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16291)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3610)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3400)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16291)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3610)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3400)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16384)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2692)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:3045)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2955)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2740)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2358)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1233)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6552)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:919)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:710)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:645)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:905)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5582)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

and following is my Java code

```
public class CategoryList extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

Button[] ChapterButton;
String[] ChapterName;
String[] ChapterNumber;
int TotalChapters = 2;
Bundle basket;
ImageButton btnSearch;
ImageButton btninfo;
ImageButton btnsettings;
ImageButton btnshare;
Typeface font;
Intent f1i;
int[] id;
int[] idiv;
TextView tvheading;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.categorylist);
    initializeData();
}

private void initializeData() {
    ChapterName = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ChapterName);
    ChapterNumber = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ChapterNumber);
    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "ERASMD.TTF");
    tvheading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHeadingtxt);
    tvheading.setTypeface(font);
    ChapterButton = new Button[TotalChapters];

    f1i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    basket = new Bundle();
    f1i.putExtra("clearCache", true);
    id = new int[TotalChapters];
    idiv = new int[TotalChapters];
    id[0] = R.id.btn1;
    id[1] = R.id.btn2;
    for (int start = 0; start < TotalChapters; start++) {
        ChapterButton[start] = (Button) findViewById(id[start]);
        ChapterButton[start].setText(ChapterNumber[start]);
        ChapterButton[start].append(Html.fromHtml("<br/>" + ChapterName[start]));
        ChapterButton[start].setTypeface(font);
        ChapterButton[start].setOnClickListener(this);
        ChapterButton[start].setPadding(5, 10, 5, 10);
    }

    btnshare = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnshare);
    btnsettings = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnsettings);
    btninfo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btninfo);
    btnSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnsearch);
    btnshare.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnsettings.setOnClickListener(this);
    btninfo.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

## Arrays

```
<string-array name="ChapterNumber">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="ChapterName">
    <item>View by</item>
    <item>View by</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Try using breakpoints

Comment: Something went wrong with your stack dump post - I assume you're about to edit it to make it easily readable?

Comment: Try to clean all and build from scratch. Probably your resources are out of sync somewhere.

Comment: @PeterMmm, tried already,didn't work...

Comment: can you add chapterName and chapterNumber arrays from string file?

Comment: what is the array size of ChapterName maybe it can be less than TotalChapters

Comment: It may be related to an attribute on one of your widgets, like a textAllCaps on an EditText. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28803492/310923

Comment: @PandiriDeepak Please check, I have added Array.

Comment: @Cedric I have checked, but i don't have any Edittext or any widget like this, Still i have checked my XML file, but i don't find anything like this,

Comment: I think issue is with TTF file you are using, try to comment that line and tryagain. @user3686177

Comment: @PandiriDeepak, Checked No issue in font. I have removed font assignment and checked but didn't worked...