# editText.getText().toString() retrieves the String all uppercase

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext, uppercase

I just want the `editText.getText().toString()` to get the normal String inserted to the EditText  but instead I'm getting it all uppercase no matter what.

Relevant XML:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_name_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/first_name_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/first_name_edit_text_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/first_name_hint_text"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Relevant Java:

```
sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
sharedPreferencesEditor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            final String firstName = sharedpreferences.getString(FIRST_NAME_KEY, "");
            sharedPreferencesEditor.putString(FIRST_NAME_KEY, firstNameEditText.getText().toString());
            sharedPreferencesEditor.apply();

            signUpButton.setText(firstName);
        }
    });
```

The `firstName` which is a `final` String variable is always uppercase.
Now whys that? and how do i solve it?

Comment: Is it anywhere else as well you are saving `FIRST_NAME_KEY` in the preferences? Also can you include code that initializes `firstNameEditText` and uses?

Comment: Man, `getText()` don`t make the text uppercase. Probably there is something else in the code that is making it upper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this at all related to your problem? [Why is my Button text forced to ALL CAPS on Lollipop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958909/why-is-my-button-text-coerced-to-all-caps-on-lollipop)

I would try adding `android:textAllCaps="false"` to the button.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the string by `log` or by `System.out.println()`. `getText()` don`t make the text uppercase. see this thread [Cannot lower case button text in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880388/cannot-lower-case-button-text-in-android-studio)

Hope it helps you.