# How to use register for buttons

Tags: android, button

How i can use **little** letters in buttons title?
I'm creating string in **res/values/strings.xml** with register, but still getting Caps.

Answer (score 2):

You could add `android:textAllCaps="false"` to the button.

The button text might be transformed to uppercase by your app's `theme` that applies to all buttons. Check `themes`/`styles` files for setting the attribute `android:textAllCaps`.

Accroding to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24880547/3212712)