# How to adjust Button text font in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I do have a `Android button` in my layout file. Similar to this:

[image]

Code for above implememtation is :

```
 button.setText(Html.fromHtml("Text in Capital Letters <br/><small>(Text in small letters)</small>"));
```

What I want to make text in "Text in Small letters" `Lowercase`. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880388/cannot-lower-case-button-text-in-android-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this property `android:textAllCaps="false"` to the button.

Or you can do it by programmatically change the transformation method of the button. `button.setTransformationMethod(null);`

Answer (score 0):

try this.It hopefully works

```
In XML file add Button

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/mText"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"/>

and in Strings.xml add

<string name="mText">TEXT In CAPITAL LETTERS\n(TEXT IN SMALL LETTERS)</string>
```