# How to make text appear in small letters except its first character in android button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button

> I have written my text in small letters but still text appears capitalized in android studio:
>
> What if i wanted to write:"Continue"?

[image]

Comment: this is because the style applied to all default Button widgets in android has the property textAllCaps set to true

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot lower case button text in android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880388/cannot-lower-case-button-text-in-android-studio)

Comment: Follow this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880388/cannot-lower-case-button-text-in-android-studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the following attribute to your button

`android:textAllCaps=false`

Comment: android:textAllCaps="false" maybe?

Answer (score 0):

`button.setTransformationMethod(null);`

Comment: Please give more context to your answer